# AWS ec2 ubuntu 18.04 LTS python upgrade

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am creating aws ec2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using cloud formation template and have user data to run commands during launch of instance. In user data, command is written to install python3.8:

**apt-get install python3.8 -y**

This cloud formation / user data is not installing python 3.8 on ec2 instance (checked after running command: python3.8 --version on ssh client).
If **manually** connect instance with ssh client (putty) and run **apt-get install python3.8 -y** , it install python 3.8 on instance. I analysed **cfn-init.log & cfn-init-output.log** at /var/log/ on ec2 instance, but didn't find any useful information for python3.8

Can anyone help me to find why cloud formation template / user data is not installing python3.8 but ssh client (putty) can install python3.8

The user data section is as below:

```
        UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
        "Fn::Sub":    
        - |
          #!/bin/bash     
          # Install Python dependencies
          apt-get update
          apt-get update && apt -y upgrade
          apt-get install dos2unix
          
          apt-get install -y python-pip
          
          apt-get install -y python3.6 python3-pip
          apt-get install python3.8 -y # installing python3.8

          pip3 install --no-cache-dir NumPy

          # Install AWS cli and init functions
          pip3 install --no-cache-dir awscli
          pip3 install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz 
          ln -s /usr/local/bin/cfn-hup /etc/init.d/cfn-hup
          cfn-init -v --stack ${STACK} --resource resources --configsets install --region ${REGION}
        - { STACK: !Ref "AWS::StackName" , REGION: !Ref "AWS::Region" }
```

Answer (score 0):

UserData runs only on instance first launch. Changes of UserData in Cloud Formation **do not force instance replacement**, so your new UserData never executes.

You have to manually delete the stack, which will delete the instance, and redeploy it.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin. I am recreating instance after stack changes. My question is specific to user data for python3.8 upgrade. Please help.

Comment: @Arvind Not sure what you mean? Please help with what? You already wrote that you know how to install python 3.8 on the instance. So what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That EC2 user-data installed python3.8 and pip successfully for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt install python3.8 -y
apt install python3.8-distutils -y

wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.8 get-pip.py
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris for your comment. After doing these changes, I recreated instance. This  command I used on ssh client (putty) to find if python 3.8 installed or not: python3.8 --version . I got response that can't find this command, so its seems like it didn't install python3.8 . Please suggest further.

Comment: I tried it in my AWS environment - and it works... not sure what the is issue on your end. Please check the [system log of the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output).